# How does Twitter sdk allows to fetch first name and last name of the user?

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using Twitter sdk in my iOS and Android application. 
I am not able to fetch first and last name. However, I am able to separate username. Username can be anything whereas first and last name would be real. 
Can anybody help with this issue please?

Comment: The Twitter API doesn’t provide that as a function, so no library can help you here.

Comment: Like facebook, Twitter user object does not imply user is made of person. Assuming that Twitter accounts you want names from does contain real names, this discussion may help you to extract first and last name from the user data : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702717/getting-first-name-last-name-email-from-twitter-using-oauth